# Howto: "letrec" in C# (lambda expression call within its definition)

Tags: c#, recursion, lambda, anonymous-recursion

Consider the factorial function defined within a method body as a lambda expression and assigned to a variable:

```
Func<int, int> factfail = n =>
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factfail(n-1);
};
```

This fails, since `factfail` isn't bound by the the local variable yet.

Is there a way to add a sort of fixpoint - by abstracting over the function itself?!

```
Func<Func<int, int>, int, int> fact_ = (fact, n) => 
{  
    if (n == 0) 
        return 1;
    else 
        return n * fact(n-1); 
};

fact_(??);
```

long story:
I need to write a recursive function that has the side effect of changing some outer state.
Therefore i am trying to write that method as a lambda expression that captures that outer state.

I am still experimenting with different styles how to write that and - besides of that one dictionary that needs to be the same for all recursive calls - i want to be as purely functional and lazy as possible.

So i was playing with LINQ, since it helps me reducing mutual data.
It also helps with understanding which parts of the code can be expressed in a functional style.

To be brief in the LINQ statement it is helpful to be able to define some helper functions in front of and i did that by binding lambda expressions to variables.

And with lamda expression i also can capture my dictionary without the need to pass its reference to the method explicitely, which is quite nice.

not sure if i am on the right track though...

Comment: Eric Lippert's must read post about this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/08/18/706398.aspx

Comment: You may be inventing Memoization - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/05/memoization-and-anonymous-recursion.aspx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find more information about recursive lambda expressions in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2007/05/11/recursive-lambda-expressions.aspx) by Mads Torgersen. He shows how to define the usual fixed point combinator. He uses factorial function as an example, so you can find your exact sample there :-).

However, in practice, you can just define a local `Func<..>` variable and then mutate it. If you want to give a name to the delegate, then it works just fine (it is a bit dirty, but simple):

```
Func<int, int> fact = null;
fact = (n) => (n == 0) ? 1 : n * fact(n-1);
```

This works, because the closure captures reference to the `fact` variable, so when you actually call it (during the recursive call), the value is not `null` anymore, but references the delegate.

Comment: For the reader's benefit, it is worth noting that this will only work with delegates, and not expression trees. And equally worth noting that there are better ways of doing a factorial than recursion ;p

Comment: Not to mention better language to exercise pure functional programming in :)

Comment: And here another blog for exactly the same topic that I find marginally easier to follow: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx